Buttons do not react
My Android app has a startup activity with a rather simple UI:
class MenuActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val that = this

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding).fillMaxWidth(),
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {
                        OutlinedButton(onClick = {
                            val intent = Intent(that, Activity1::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }) {
                            Text(stringResource(R.string.a1))
                        }
                        OutlinedButton(onClick = {
                            val intent = Intent(that, Activity2::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }) {
                            Text(stringResource(R.string.a2))
                        }
                        OutlinedButton(onClick = {
                            val intent = Intent(that, Activity3::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }) {
                            Text(stringResource(R.string.a3))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This used to work - clicking either of the buttons would bring me to the respective activities.
Then, as I was trying to solve some other issues (#1, #2), I did a few changes to the code (but not actually to this MenuActivity), referenced the GSON library, and upgraded from Android Studio 2024.1.2 to 2024.2.1.
When I launch the app now in the emulator (I have tried with several different virtual devices), the menu buttons are displayed, but they do not react to any clicks. Not at all. There is no visual feedback from clicking, no other activities are opened, no breakpoints are hit, even Logcat does not display anything when I add a Log.d call to the click event handler.
In fact, while the Logcat window is filled with all kinds of messages as usual, none at all arrive when I click any of the buttons, i.e. there also is no runtime exception thrown at that moment or anything like that.
How can I analyze this? Is there anything in particular I should watch out for in Logcat/scan the log output for?

UPDATE: Here's the MyAppTheme definition as requested in the comments:
@Composable
fun MyAppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}


UPDATE: The clock on the emulated device keeps showing the current time. Thus, the emulator is not frozen. I suspect it is just ignoring all mouse clicks for some reason.

Your code is correct. Try reverting your code. Datastore and SharedPreferences aren't relevant. I tested changes from issue #2 and no errors occurred :D

@NguyễnMinhKhoa: I have reverted my code to the last commit that still worked. Still zero reaction to my mouse clicks.

Have you run clean, sync, and rebuild?  You may also need to Invalidate your Caches

@RobertJamison: I have done all of these. They do not change anything.

How does your MyAppTheme look like? Maybe it is consuming all inputs. I tried the code and replaced the intents with prints, and it worked fine on a new and clean project.

@basti394: I have added the full source of MyAppTheme. I think I had not looked into that file before; presumably, it was auto-generated in the beginning in the course of starting a new project.

I'm guessing you've already done this, but for a long shot:  It is possible that when you call your intent, it is failing gracefully rather than throwing an error.  Try putting your log statements before and after the intent lines.

@RobertJamison: Indeed, I had (and just have again, to verify) put the Log.d calls in the beginning and the end of the onClick handler, but neither message appears in Logcat.
